# Call a function when screen is unlocked

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have opened and focused app on android phone, and I lock the screen. When I unlock it, I want to call a specific function.

I was thinking about `Qt.application.state`, but how to call function when it has changed?

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You searching for `void QGuiApplication::applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState state)`.

From [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#applicationStateChanged):

> void QGuiApplication::applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState state)
>
> This signal is emitted when the state of the application changes.
>
> This function was introduced in Qt 5.2.

Just connect to this signal at your `C++` part of code, check `state == Qt::ApplicationActive` and trigger some function inside you `QML` part.

Comment: what is wrong? `QObject::connect(app, SIGNAL(app.applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState state)), &stater, SLOT(stateChanged()));`

Comment: Should be `QObject::connect(&app, SIGNAL(applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState state)), &stater, SLOT(stateChanged()));`